# Converting days into years, months and days

Tags: python

I know I can use relativedelta to calculate difference between two dates in the calendar. However, it doesn't feet my needs.

I must consider 1 year = 365 days and/or 12 months; and 1 month = 30 days.

To transform 3 years, 2 months and 20 days into days, all I need is this formula: `(365x3)+(30x2)+20`, which is equal to 1175.

However, how can I transform days into years, months and days, considering that the amount of days may or may not be higher than 1 month or 1 year? Is there a method on Python that I can use?

Mathemacally, I could divide 1175 by 365, multiply the decimals of the result by 365, divide the result by 30 and multiply the decimals of the result by 30. But how could I do that in Python?

Comment: Did you tried using  https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta module?

Comment: Yes, but that would use the calendar (result may vary, depending on the year and the month), I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to multiply the decimals, use modulo `%` to find remainder

[READ MORE ABOUT IT HERE](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

```
totalDays = 120

years = totalDays//365
months = (totalDays%365)//30
days = (totalDays%365)%30

print(years,months,days)
```

```
0 0 12
```

Comment: If I use 4464 days in your code (12y - 02m - 20d), it will return 12 2 24 instead. The result must be very precise, since it'll be used to calculate benefits (like parole) for sentenced people. Could you help me out figuring out what's wrong? This would be exactly what I need, if I get the correct result.